# Promise chaining, chain promise object

Tags: javascript, promise, angular-promise

I would like to chain promise object, but the problem that the second `then` block is executed before the chained promise object got resolved.

```
service.webService1()
  .then(data => {
    if (data.flag) { // true
      return service.webService2() // returns a promise
    }
    return $q.resolve({})
  })
  .then(data => {
    // some logic
    // data is undefined here, should be the result of
    // service.webService2() call
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // err handling
  })
```

Comment: if this line `return service.webService2()` is executed, then it shouldn't behave like you say it does

Comment: its executed after the second `then` block

Comment: Are you perhaps getting confused by the fact that `data` in the second `then` is the data returned by `webService2`?
Also note that you can just `return {}`, there is no need to wrap the result of a `then` callback in a promise, `then` will do that for you automatically.

Comment: Maybe check the implementation of `webService2` and check that it really does return a promise. Perhaps you forgot a `return` statement there?

Comment: When I debug, the webService2 was executed, and I'm sure that the `data.flag` was `true`
Also I didn't forgot the return statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that I forgot to return my promise in the `service.webService2()` function. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show how the working code is different than the one in your question?